# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: java, android

here is my code
App is crashing when opening this activity
Please help
Below is the error
This is not the full code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ModelTimeSlot  modelTimeSlot = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.checkBox.setText(modelTimeSlot.name);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(modelTimeSlot.selected);
    holder.checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));
    int hr = Integer.parseInt(currentHrs);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(currentMin);
    int h = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTimeSlot.endTime.charAt(0))
            + String.valueOf(modelTimeSlot.endTime.charAt(1)));

    int m = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTimeSlot.endTime.charAt(2))
            + String.valueOf(modelTimeSlot.endTime.charAt(3)));
```

And here is the error

```
at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494)
at mrhot.com.mrhot.Adapter.AdapterTimeSlot.onBindViewHolder(AdapterTimeSlot.java:91)
at mrhot.com.mrhot.Adapter.AdapterTimeSlot.onBindViewHolder(AdapterTimeSlot.java:28)
```

Comment: How many chars are in `modelTimeSlot.endTime`? You're trying to access positions that don't exist. If length is 1, then the only position that exists is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Print value of your `modelTimeSlot.endTime` and check it's length. The trace is very clearly saying length is less than the index you are passing i.e. `0` or `2` or `3`.

Comment: Still not getting it

Comment: print `modelTimeSlot.endTime` man, you will see length of `modelTimeSlot.endTime` is less than 3

Comment: check length before doing `charAt` for example

```if(modelTimeSlot.endTime.length()>3){
   modelTimeSlot.endTime.charAt(3)
}```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in arrayList.get(position), arrayList.size() < position this is causing outOfBound exception, look what you have written in getCount() method